# How is it possible to create instance of Map class despite being abstract

Tags: oop, object, dart, abstract-class, abstract

I am new to dart.

I noticed that [`Map`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Map-class.html) is an abstract class, then how is it possible to create an instance of it, by doing something like this:

```dart
final Map map = {};
```

Can somebody enlighten me about it, how is it an abstract class then. Is abstract in dart, not consistent with other OOP languages?

Answer (score 1):

"Map" itself is an abstract class, but in Dart you can provide a 'default' concrete implementation of an abstract class using a Factory constructor.

To create an instance of a Map through a Factory constructor:

final Map map = Map();

See Dart Map Class Documentation:

```
Constructors

Map()
    Creates a Map instance with the default implementation, LinkedHashMap. [...]
    factory
```

from https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Map-class.html

Comment: You are saying factory constructors can provide concrete instance of an abstract class??

Comment: No! Factory constructors may be used to provide an specific concrete implementation of an abstract class (which is another class). It IS the case of "Map" factory constructor you mentioned. In this case the concrete implementation provided from Map Factory constructor is LinkedHashMap class. In other words, you are not creating an instance of an abstract class (the Map class) since this is impossible. You are creating a instance of a concrete class (LinkedHashMap)

Comment: Note that `LinkedHashMap` is, itself, abstract. The actual type instantiated is one of a few internal classes such as `_InternalLinkedHashMap`.

Answer (score -1):

It isn't possible to instantiate abstract class because it is... abstract aka incomplete. Your question is not clear and I am not sure where you took this statament from but I dare to say you misunderstood reading something somewhere.

Comment: I have edited question with declaration  code. Isn't map object in that code typed Map?  How am I able to declare it that way? I can't declare it that way with any other abstract class

Comment: I might have misunderstood or confused something. If you could clarify the confusion.

Comment: Please read about "map literals": https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#maps